# Jquery append list and save with cookie plugin

Tags: jquery, cookies, html-lists, appendchild

I have a script with which I can save plain text using click event and cookie plugin:

```
$('.fields').click(function(e) {
    var text = $('#inputBox').val();
    $.cookie('demoCookie',text,{expires: 7, path: '/' });
    $(".jq-text").text(text);
    .....
```

The cookie is called like this:

```
var cookie = $.cookie('demoCookie');    
if (cookie){
    $('.jq-text').text(cookie).show();
```

So now I want to append a list with a link and of course save it with a cookie:

```
$('.fields').click(function(e) {
    var text = $('#inputBox').val();
    $.cookie('demoCookie',text,{expires: 7, path: '/' });
    $(".jq-text").append('<li><a href="' + text + '">' + text + '</a></li>');
```

I cant get it to work: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dx6CN/1/)

The text is saved but not the list and a href.

ps The problem might be that the dynamically created list is gone the second one refreshes the page..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting the value every time you save one. That's why you can only read back the last one you added. You'd need to read what is already there, append to it, then save it again.

It will probably be a good idea to create an Array to save your values and make it a JSON string when you write it to the cookie. Then when you're reading it back, you can parse the JSON into an array again (parseJSON jQuery command) and add your new value.

Here's an edited fiddle showing what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/dx6CN/3/

Comment: Makes sense, to bad it involves lots of work, I was hoping for some small change in the script

Comment: Just edited my answer to include an edited fiddle, not that many changes :)

Comment: Thanks for writing the Fiddle(: I always learn better by looking at code, thanks for showing me how.

Comment: Hope it all makes sense for you since I didn't comment it! Good luck with the rest of it! :)

Comment: Well I cant possibly ask you to do everything now can I...:)